# I think my slider turtle is sick

Tags: turtles

I have a red ear slider that is less than one year old.  After the last tank cleaning he is less active and staying in corners of the tank nose first. He isn't eating much and isn't that active.  I used bleach like always with the right amount of water.  I am concerned that maybe there is something wrong with the water or I missed something.   Not sure what to do?

Comment: Is there any more symptoms other than the one's you've stated already?

Comment: Hope your pet is doing fine.